# Objective-c: How to make multiple async service calls and block until they are all complete

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I have a senario that requires me to make multiple call to a web api. The following is an example.

```
getDataAsync:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withCompletion: (void (^)(NSDictionary*))completion {

    __block int counter = n; // the number of async blocks
    __block NSMutableDictionary *output = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    void (^returnBlock)(void) = ^{
        counter--;
        if(counter != 0) return;
        completion(@{@"return": output});
        return;
    };
    void (^getResourceA)(void) = ^{
        [service getResourceA : dictionary[@"idA"] completion:
        ^(ServiceResult results, MyResourceA *a, NSString *errMsg) {
            [output setValue:a.value forKey:a.name];
            returnBlock(); 
        }];
    };
    // followed by n-1 other blocks like getResourceA
    //... 
}
```

I want to use the built in `dispatch_queue` rather than my own custom solution here. How can I do that given the inner completion block used by the asynchronous service call?

Also any other advice on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dispatch groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19) have been invented for this purpose:

```
dispatch_group_t requestGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(requestGroup, queue, ^{
    // ...
});
dispatch_group_wait(requestGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
completionBlock();
```

Or instead of waiting:

```
dispatch_group_notify(requestGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completionBlock();
});
```

Also, instead of dispatching blocks to the group, you can also enter and leave a group manually, which works well with asynchronous service APIs:

```
dispatch_group_enter(requestGroup);
[service getResourceA : dictionary[@"idA"] completion: ^(ServiceResult results, MyResourceA *a, NSString *errMsg) {
    [output setValue:a.value forKey:a.name];
    dispatch_group_leave(requestGroup);
}];
```

Comment: The second solution was the one to work for me. I don't think the first one can work given the async service call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dispatch_group_t`. See [Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25).

The topic doesn't mention it, but use [`dispatch_group_notify`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_notify) to register a block instead of waiting inline.

Comment: That sounds like what I want, Could you give me and anyone else that might come later on an example of how that would look in code?